# Convert p12 to gpg files that thunderbird can understand

Tags: openssl, openssh

I have a .p12 certificate emitted by spanish authorities. I would like to use that certificate for encryption in thunderbird. For that, I am trying to convert the certificate to gpg format so that I can import it in thunderbird, without success.

I have managed to create OpenSSH certificate and public key, but can't find a way to creating OpenGPG certificates from the p12 or the openssh certificates.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that.  While they both use asymmetric cryptography, they contain incompatible information.  Thunderbird can use S/MIME which could use the PKCS#12 file from the Spanish authorities to encrypt and/or sign emails.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried that, but I have several email accounts and the pkcs file only have one of them, so I can't use it for other accounts. What should I do in this case, generate several gpg keys, one per email account?

Comment: A GPG key can have multiple IDs, so you could have one key for all your accounts. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29851/how-many-openpgp-keys-should-i-make